# When to use XPath in RSpec + Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, rspec, capybara

When do you use XPath and why?

Following lines both match a submit button with "Post" value. Is there any merits in using XPath?

```
it { should have_selector("input[type=submit][value='Post']") }

it { should have_xpath("//input[@value='Post']") }
```

Also, are there any situations that using XPath is critical in RSpec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath allows to more specifically "specify" the element you're referring to, whereas just selecting the element "by name", sometimes gives ambiguity as to which element you're actually referring. Especially on complex pages, you often get complaints of Capybara that "multiple elements match". In that case, you can use XPath do specify which element you're actually referring to.

In case you have ambiguity, you can also add

```
match: :prefer_exact
```

to "steer" the selection, e.g. if both a "password" and a "password confirmation" field are present on your page, you can put something like

```
fill_in 'Password', with: @visitor[:password], match: :prefer_exact
```

My personal experience is, that by using prefer_exact, you can mostly resolve ambiguity, so that you seldom require XPath...